# it is impossible to group notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I use a notice in my project. I want to group notifications. Please tell me how to do it? I tried to do it by example [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html#AddGroup)

but nothing came of it. each notification is displayed separately.

here is my code:

```
private static int id =0;
final static String GROUP_KEY_GUEST = "group_key_guest";
...
private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
        if(notificationManager==null){
            notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification notification   = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm))
                .setTicker("Новое сообщение")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_GUEST)
                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(id++, notification);
    }

@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("content");
        generateNotification(context,title, message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the link that you posted in question is related to grouping the notifications on wearable devices not on mob/tab devices. to group your notifications into one notification on mob/tab use BigTextStyle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the issue is that group notifications just support Android L. Please make sure your device version is Android L(20). Or you can run the project on an android L phone, then try it again.